# How to hide minimize buttons on a MPart?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I wrote an rcp application in eclipse juno and I have created an application model with a trimmed window that contains a perspective stack with one perspective. This perspective contains a partsashcontainer with two part stacks. Each part stack contains one part.

If I run the application each part has a minimize button which I want to disable. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the minimize buttons of the `MPartStack`s by adding a style attribute to the `.MPartStack` selector in your .css file:

```
.MPartStack {
  swt-minimize-visible: false;
}
```

(Found at: http://garethcooper.com/2012/05/eclipse-4-css/)